# Load/include javascript file in Ajax success

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i want know if it's possible load a Javascript file in ajax response in an html page, this is the code:

```
<script src="../assets/plugins/myScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myFunc();

    function myFunc(){

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "load_page.php",
                data: { type:'testA' },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#test_id").html(html);
                    //here i want reload the script i have import above myScript.js
                }
            });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need to reload it?

Comment: You can use `$.getScript()`.

Comment: But maybe you should rewrite `myScript.js` so it doesn't need to be reloaded. It could define a function that you call to initialize what it does -- you would call then when the page is first loaded, and then after the AJAX response. Or it should use event delegation to bind handlers to elements that are added dynamically.

Comment: I agree with Barmar - you shouldn't need to reload the script file.

Comment: i need to reload it because with the ajax i load some content that need a javascript, to animate it, but when the javascript it's loaded there is nothing to animate, because the ajax haven't finished, so i think that reloading the javascript that have the animation, can animate the content that the ajax load